# Maximize Terminal Window on Launcher where Terminal=True

Tags: gnome, launcher, vim

I have searched the internet for a while now, but have not found a suitable answer.  I have vim installed with a .desktop file to start vim (not gvim!).  In the .desktop file it has a Terminal=True.

Now I also want vim to start maximized, but since I do not have a terminal command I can not add the option --maximized

Also: I do NOT want to start all terminals maximized, just the vim window and only if I start it using the .desktop icon.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First open the vim. Then maximize it. 
Type

```
  :set lines
  :set columns
```

Remember the numbers. For me, 44 lines and 168 columns are there in maximized terminal.

You can set up an auto command in your ~/.vimrc such that terminal maximizes every time when You open a file.

```
 :au BufEnter *.* :set lines=44 columns=168
```

Now, every time when you open a new file, the window will be expanded automatically.

Or, you can put a command like this in ~/.vimrc

```
 :command! Max :set lines=44 columns=168
```

Then, you can expand the window by typing

```
 :Max
```

It will be expanded.